# C++ Formula trouble

Tags: c++, rsa

I am entering the values, `p=3`, `q=11`, `e=7` and `m=2` in the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Calculate{
    int q, p, n, d, e, c, zeta , m, encryption;
public:
    Calculate(){
        cout << "Enter P" << endl;
        cin >> p;

        cout << "Enter Q" << endl;
        cin >> q;

        cout << "Enter E" << endl;
        cin >> e;

        cout << "Enter M" << endl;
        cin >> m;

        assign();
    }

    void test(){
        while (e >= zeta || e <=1){
            cout << "Enter a correct value for E" << endl;
            cin >> e;
        }
        encrypt();
    };

    void assign(){
        n = p*q;
        zeta = (p-1)*(q-1);

        for ( int j = 2; j < n; j++){
            if ( (j*e) % zeta == 1){    
                d = j;
                j = n;
            }
        } 
        test();
    };

    void encrypt(){
        cout << m << endl;
        cout << e << endl;
        cout << n << endl;
        encryption = (m ^ e) % n;
        cout << "The encryption Is: " << encryption << endl;
    };


};

//------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Calculate calc;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For some reason `encryption` always equals `5`, which makes no sense to me since `2 ^ 7 % 33 == 29`.

Do I have an error in my code somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here, most likely, is that the `^` operator is not exponent, it's the *bitwise exclusive or* operator. 2 XOR 7 is, indeed, 5.

You probably want [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: Also notice that there are way more efficient algorithms to calculate modular exponentiations (especially when you go outside the realm of what "regular" integers can do, as usual with RSA).